# Can I use different siunitx "S" table formats for different rows?

Tags: tables, siunitx

In this table, I'd like to use `1.2+-1.2` alignment for all rows, except for one. How can I make the fourth row align with the others at the plus-minus symbol, but ignore the decimal points?

Trying to get the fourth row into the alignment by using a format like `2.2+-2.2` simply creates too much space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.2+-2.2]}}
  one row & 1.7(8) & 2.1(11) & 1.9(08) \\
  another row & 1.1(7) & 1.1(07) & 1.2(06) \\
  a third row & 1.4(7) & 1.9(09) & 1.4(07) \\
  a special fourth row & 56(12) & 10(9) & 53(23) \\
  and number five & 0.85(08) & 0.84(0.10) & 0.85(0.08) \\
  and number six & 0.85(08) & 0.84(0.10) & 0.85(0.08) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can, look up `\tablenum` in the `siunitx` manual. I do not remember if it requires a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrapper.

Comment: Thank you @daleif. I did try that but didn't manage, so I figured I had misunderstood the command. With this cell content: `\tablenum[table-format=2.1+-2.1]{56(12)}` I get the error: `Argument of \tablenum  has an extra }.`. Can you see any obvious mistake?

Comment: Aha, I didn't realise it needs `multicolumn`. I'll give that a try.

Comment: @daleif Wrapping tablenum in multicolumn solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @daleif or Anna, please one of you add an answer to the question, to help future users (answers in comments are easily lost)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\tablenum` solves this. It needs to be wrapped in a multicolumn to work, and additionally, you need to select the number of digits so that the plus-minus symbol will align with the other rows.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=1.2+-1.2]}}
  one row & 1.7(8) & 2.1(11) & 1.9(08) \\
  another row & 1.1(7) & 1.1(07) & 1.2(06) \\
  a third row & 1.4(7) & 1.9(09) & 1.4(07) \\
  a special fourth row
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tablenum[table-format=2+-2]{56(12)}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tablenum[table-format=2+-2]{10(9)}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tablenum[table-format=2+-2]{53(23)}} \\
  and number five & 0.85(08) & 0.84(0.10) & 0.85(0.08) \\
  and number six & 0.85(08) & 0.84(0.10) & 0.85(0.08) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @daleif Do you mean for the fourth row? I thought it would look even stranger to align on the decimal point (`2.2+-2.2` for the entire column) due to the differences in order of magnitude causing spaces. This is how my actual table looks like: https://imgur.com/gMoeJ10 -- what would you change to make it look better and less strange? I'm very happy to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Just ignore me, I read your data wrong

Comment: @Anna  Maybe change degrees to rads so everything is within a good range

Comment: @yannisl Thanks for the suggestion! I'm happy with radians, but as it's an anatomical angle, it's easier for the reader to interpret in degrees. I also considered changing the last two rows to millimeters and percentage, but that coefficient is never expressed in percent, only as a unit-less fraction.

Comment: It does look good as is. The eye sees the plusminuses so is still good typography. Well done and is also very good you sharing your solutions.